# Passing files blueimp fileupload IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, file-upload, blueimp

I have a problem using blueimp fileupload.

When I'm trying to upload a file in FireFox or Google Chrome I get on my .NET side the files with length and filename.

[image]

If I try it in IE I get an empty stream with no content length and no filename. I'm sure my filearray is right, as it works in FF and Chrome whith length and filename.

[image]

Can anyone give me the right hint?

Here is how my setup looks like:

```
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        $(this).fileupload({
            dropZone: $('#' + content).find('.fileupload').length > 1 ? $('#' + content + ' .container' + that.closest('.standardJoins').find('.tStampJoin').val()) : $(document),
            pasteZone: $('#' + content).find('.fileupload').length > 1 ? $('#' + content + ' .container' + that.closest('.standardJoins').find('.tStampJoin').val()) : $(document),
            singleFileUploads: false,
            url: '/service/serviceAIO.aspx',
            multipart: false,
            change: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    fileArray[fileArray.length] = data.files[0];
                });
            }
...
```

For some reasons I cannot submit the form until a button is pressed. After pressing the button I am submitting the form this way:

```
$('#' + content + ' .fileupload:visible:first').fileupload('send', { files: fileArray });
```

I have multiple instances of the file uploader as it is a single page layout with multiple tabs (jQuery UI).

On serverside I'm getting the request with:

```
Request.Files("files[]")
```

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: No one any suggestion?